# Kubernetes - wait for other pod to be ready

Tags: kubernetes

I have two applications - **app1** and **app2**, where **app1** is a `config server` that holds configs for **app2**. I have defined `/readiness` endpoint in **app1** and need to wait till it returns `OK` status to start up pods of **app2**.

It's crucial that deployment of **app2** wait till `kubernetes` receives `Http Status OK` from **/readiness** endpoint in **app1** as it's a configuration server and holds crucial configs for app2.

Is it possible to do this kind of deployment dependency?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#what-can-init-containers-be-used-for) (also, see this [blog post](https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-pods-life/) for some background re timing) but a better, more Kubernetes-native pattern is to use retries and timeouts rather than hard-coding dependencies in this way.

Comment: I understand that *"use retries and timeouts"* is the approach in Kubernetes, but it clogs my logging so much with failures. It creates a new problem; filtering 'normal' failures due to this design pattern. A 'simple' dependency management like "do not schedule before <pod/deployment/replicaset/...> is ready" would be SO MUCH helpful to reduce this problem and more obvious in monitoring the cluster than looking at a "initContainer" to be run and you don't know it's actually init'ing or just waiting.

Answer (score 41):

You can use [`initContainers`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#init-containers-in-use). Following is an example of how you can do in your `YAML` file

```
initContainers:
- name: wait-for-other-pod
  image: docker.some.image
  args:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - >
    set -x;
    while [ $(curl -sw '%{http_code}' "http://www.<your_pod_health_check_end_point>.com" -o /dev/null) -ne 200 ]; do
      sleep 15;
    done
```

I have used `curl` to hit the health check endpoint, you can use any other UNIX command to check if the other pod is ready.

If you have a dependency on k8s resources, you can make use of [stackanetes/kubernetes-entrypoint](https://github.com/stackanetes/kubernetes-entrypoint) example:

```
initContainers:
- command:
  - kubernetes-entrypoint
  name: init-dependency-check
  env:
  - name: POD_NAME
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        apiVersion: v1
        fieldPath: metadata.name
  - name: NAMESPACE
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        apiVersion: v1
        fieldPath: metadata.namespace
  - name: DEPENDENCY_SERVICE
  - name: DEPENDENCY_DAEMONSET
  - name: DEPENDENCY_CONTAINER
  - name: DEPENDENCY_POD_JSON
    value: '[{"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/name":"postgres"}}]'
  - name: COMMAND
    value: echo done
  image: projects.registry.vmware.com/tcx/snapshot/stackanetes/kubernetes-entrypoint:latest
  securityContext:
    privileged: true
    runAsUser: 0
```

In the above example, the pod with initContainer `init-dependency-check` will wait until pod with label `"app.kubernetes.io/name":"postgres"` is in the Running state. Likewise you can make use of `DEPENDENCY_SERVICE`, `DEPENDENCY_DAEMONSET`, `DEPENDENCY_CONTAINER`

Comment: `200 ]` there need to be a space between "200" and "]" please fix it for newbies like me :)

Comment: For `docker.some.image`, one can use `k8s.gcr.io/busybox` or `busybox` from Docker Hub.

Comment: `busybox` from docker hub does not contain curl command.

Comment: Entrypoint WARNING: 2022/09/03 21:16:30 entrypoint.go:72: Resolving dependency Pod on same host with labels map[app:development-bitcoin] in namespace default failed: Getting POD: development-lightning-8469b65998-pqp6z failed : pods "development-lightning-8469b65998-pqp6z" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default" .

Getting this permission error when the init container runs. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @PatrickGeyer you have not configured the RBAC correctly.

Comment: @Vishrant it would be useful if you provide minimal config for RBAC

Answer (score 15):

```yaml
initContainers:
    - name: wait-for-dependent-service
      image: stefanevinance/wait-for-200
      env:
        - name: URL
          value: http://dependent-service.{{.Release.Namespace}}.svc.cluster.local:3000
```

Using https://hub.docker.com/r/stefanevinance/wait-for-200/

Answer (score 9):

In my case the application **don't have a /readiness endpoint**. We have master pods and worker pods and we want the worker pods to start up only after master pod is up and running. The master pod runs an application listening on TCP port 80. I ended up using netcat in an init container in the worker pod.

```
nc -z <host> <port>
```

**nc** will check if the port is open, exiting with 0 on success, 1 on failure.

```
initContainers:
- name: wait-for-master-before-starup
  image: busybox
  command:  ["sh", "-c", "until nc -z master-service 80 > /dev/null; do echo Waiting for master.; sleep 2; done;"]
```

If you already have a health/readiness endpoint, its much better to use it like mentioned in other answers here.

Answer (score 5):

Using [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) is actually quite easy:

```
  initContainers:
  - name: wait-for-app1
    image: image-docker-containing-sh
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - /usr/app/wait-for-it.sh app1:<portapp1> -t 0
```

Of course retries and timeouts are the way to go, but this works great as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

same as @Vishrant Answer...
just other way to write bash commands in single line in YAML file

```
  initContainers:
  - name: wait-for-some-pod
    image: yourDockerImage
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    args: ['while [ $(curl -ksw "%{http_code}" "https://<pod_health_check_end_point>" -o /dev/null) -ne 200 ]; do sleep 5; echo "health check failed . Waiting for the service..."; done']
```

Comment: @foobarbecue its a way to get http code from curl response.

Comment: Ah thanks, I see now. With so many layers of tools it's hard to know if this is k8s, bash, or curl. Ref: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#:~:text=-w%2C%20--write-out,by%20using%20%25%7Bstderr%7D.