# How to check if desired number of pods are up and active in init containers using helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a use case where few deployment pods have to wait for few other stateful pods to be active.
This can be done via init containers in k8s. How could I ensure that desired no. of stateful pods are active now using init containers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes - wait for other pod to be ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079849/kubernetes-wait-for-other-pod-to-be-ready)

Comment: The easiest way to do it is for your application container to just make the request, and crash and restart if it's not ready.  But the question above has some specific examples of using init containers to do it.