# Traffic is getting send to unready pod in kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, readinessprobe

We have added readiness probe and the container is in unready state until it is fully loaded but in case of horizontal autoscaling a new pod which is in unready state starts getting traffic due to which request are failing. We are using nginx ingress controller for loadbalancing and service type is of ClusterIP[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHAze.jpg)

We tried adding readiness probes , probe is working and making sure that container is not ready state but somehow it is getting traffic[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blNhP.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

Infra-cluster traffic is handled by the Services and the Services route as soon as the Pod is RUNNING.

What you can do is configure an initContainer that does a health check of the localhost:PORT of your service.

Check it out here: [Kubernetes - wait for other pod to be ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079849/kubernetes-wait-for-other-pod-to-be-ready)

If you have the ability to create automatisms, you might also consider using the `kubectl wait` command:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait